# Compact code on Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, css, performance, visual-studio, organizer

On Visual Studio whenever you have a sentence with { }, it creates a option box in the left side with a "-" that allow you to collapse the code and later expand with "+". Is a great way to keep code minimized and clean.

I wonder if there's a way to force that on code without using {} (which will give errors). Would be really good for .CSS

Comment: you can use `#region`

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm for .css.

/*#region myRegion*/


 "Lorem ipsum ascidi...:"

/*#endregion*/
Too bad is not working for Javascript or Typescript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separating the code by #regions really improved my .css organization.

Minimal view and organized by topics since it let you close and open regions.

```css
/*#region ---------- BUTTONS */

#button_LF {
    border-radius: 15px 25px 15px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right:10px;     
    padding-bottom:3px;
    cursor:pointer;     
}
#button_RF {
    border-radius: 15px 25px 15px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right:30px;     
    padding-bottom:25px;
    cursor:pointer;     
}

/*#endregion    */
```

Hotkeys <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to Expand/Collapse everything get pretty useful to work with.
Having a final look like this:

[image]